# Shortcut for Adding #-Symbol at the End of Each Line in R / RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to add a #-symbol at the end of each line of my code in RStudio. Consider the following example:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

The output should be:

```
aaaaa#
bbbbb#
ccccc#
```

It is possible to add a #-symbol at the beginning of each line with the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + C. Is something similar available for the end of a line?

Comment: We could build an [Rstudio addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) that does that, and attach a shortcut to it

Comment: @Aurèle Thank you for the hint, I didn't know that this is possible.